# Is Rose Clear safe to use on Clematis?

Tags: pest-control

I have greenfly on my clematis. Rose Clear worked well on my roses, but will it harm a clematis? The clematis has only just been planted into the ground this year, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Note that Rose Clear contains [neonicotinoid pesticides](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/911/99) and there are indications that these pesticides are resposible for the decline in bee populations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The active ingredients are  [Triticonazole](http://www.pesticideinfo.org/Detail_Chemical.jsp?Rec_Id=PC37450) and [Acetamiprid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetamiprid). It should not be toxic to a clematis.  Both ingredients claim to be of low toxicity to humans but appropriate safety gear should be worn when applying this product.

If you are concerned about toxicity for your plant you can use five to ten ml of dish soap to one liter of water as a spray.  This is a very effective control for greenfly/aphids and most soft skinned insects.